# Impala: change the column type prior to perform the aggregation function for group by

Tags: sql, database, impala

I have a table, my_table:

```
transaction_id    |   money     |  team
--------------------------------------------
    1             |   10        |   A
    2             |   20        |   B
    3             |   null      |   A
    4             |   30        |   A
    5             |   16        |   B
    6             |   12        |   B
```

When I group by team, I can compute max, min through query:

```
select team, max(money), min(money) from my_table group by team
```

However, I can't do avg and sum because there is null. i.e:

```
select team, avg(money), sum(money) from my_table group by team
```

would fail.

Is there a way to change the column type prior to computing the avg and sum? i.e. I want the output to be:

```
team   |  avg(money)   |  sum(money)
--------------------------------------
 A     |  20           |  40
 B     |  16           |  48
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Impala but SQL already works as you've desired. Does Impala have a COALESCE or NULLIF function? You could use those with zero for the SUM. Handling AVG would be trickier.

Comment: the documentation says, `Rows with a NULL value for the specified column are ignored`, both for `sum` and `avg`.

Comment: Did you test the query before asking?

Comment: @sstan: This is the error I got: HiveServer2Error: AnalysisException: AVG requires a numeric or timestamp parameter: avg(money)
Or how do I treat money as numeric if it is not defined so in the table? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that `money` is not numeric?  Then why does your question give the impression that it is, and that the only concern are the `null` values?  You should edit your question to be much clearer about what your actual problem is.

Comment: @sstan: I am not sure what caused the problem yet. Originally I thought it was because there is null. But according to the reply, people said null is not an issue? So I am just guessing what are the other possible causes for the problem...

Comment: That's why it's always important to post the error details that you actually got, instead of posting what you think the solution should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per documentation provided by Cloudera your query should be working as-is. Both [AVG Function](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_avg.html) and 
[SUM Function](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_sum.html) ignore null.

```
SELECT team, AVG(money), SUM(money)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY team
```

UPDATE: Per your comment, again I'm not familiar with Impala. Presumably standard SQL will work. Your error appears to be a datatype issue.

```
SELECT team, AVG(CAST(money AS INT)), SUM(CAST(money AS INT))
FROM my_table
GROUP BY team
```

Comment: This is the error I got: HiveServer2Error: AnalysisException: AVG requires a numeric or timestamp parameter: avg(money) Or how do I treat money as numeric if it is not defined so in the table? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the sum by the count:

```
SELECT team, SUM(money)/COUNT(money) AS AVG, SUM(money)
FROM team
GROUP BY team
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba381/4